2 grounds on the same board
Let's assume we have a board that has some I/O pins and some communication interfaces like RS232 and analog inputs (bottom board).
Now we want to add some extra functionality and we choose to expand it with a hat board, like arduino does (top board).
However the extra features are high current solid state switches with mosfets.
By high current I mean 2A-3A DC.
There will be 10-20 power ouputs. Mix of low and high side - most of them low side (voltage up to 30V DC).
The header pins are designed to provide communication interfaces only, there is 3.3V and ground but I don't think it can withstand.
That means I need to provide a separate power to the extra hat board.
The question is: What will happen if you miss the second power ground on the hat board while the low side switches (N-channel mosfets) are ON?
The current will go throught the header connectors and out of the main port.
What parts should I take care of to avoid mixing power ground with digital ground on the board below?
How can I prevent high current from flowing to the main board or through the header pins if the black (ground) cable or power ground connection to the upper board becomes disconnected?
One thought is to use optocouplers to drive the mosfets and keep the power circuits isolated.
The maximum operating voltage for both boards is up to 30V DC.
Reference picture


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Added a schematic.
24V comes from the power connector of the top board.
LOAD and LOAD_GND comes from the top board for one of the power outputs.
MCU_PIN is a control signal from the top board maybe an I/O expander or another microcontroller.
The ground is common in that case and it is also conntected to the ground of the bottom board.
And the two possible paths.
blue: the current goes throught the power connector on the top (bottom remains undisturbed.
red: the power ground disconnects and the current flows down.
Connections:

simulate this circuit


@Burglups if the black cable on the top board disconnects, the only path will be the main board through the header pins.

@Burglups I added a schematic.

@Burglups I added it

@Burglups Yes it is the same power. So basically I want to avoid disturbing the digital circuits in case the LOAD_GND disconnects

If the two power supplies are unrelated then nothing will happen. You can think of them as two separate batteries. Each board connected to it's own supply and return wire. So the large drive currents cannot flow between two boards, because only low current FET/transistor control signals and their return currents flow between boards.
If you use e.g. two power supplies that already share a ground connection (e.g. both supplies connect the ground return to mains plug earth wire and then earth wires are connected between mains sockets), then currents will take all possible routes and disconnecting the high current return wire will make all current go through logic board (and via earth wire inside walls) back to high current power supply.
In latter case, you need galvanic isolation between boards, for example optocouplers, so that the grounds of the two boards have no connection between them.

The solution is to reverse the hat and turn it into a mainboard.
So you can build a mainboard with:

Power input connector, up to 30V DC as mentioned in the question
Power switches and their output connectors
DC-DC converter (examples) to generate 5V or 3V3 for the microcontroller module, with associated components mentioned in the datasheet (usually caps)

Then you mount the microcontroller module on this main board, powered through its pin headers. You get a self contained system that does not need an extra 5V AC/DC power supply.
All the high current will flow on the main board, the microcontroller module is connected to it through its pins, so there is no way for the problem described in the question to occur, unless you connect wires to the microcontroller module and make a short circuit. But if you build a mainboard, you can take the opportunity to put more convenient connectors on it instead of using the MCU pin headers, which also solves this problem.
If the MCU module has several ground pins, take care that the mainboard ground plane is not interrupted below it, as the module could then act as a bridge across this gap in the ground plane and conduct high current through its PCB.
If the module has a separate power input like USB, you will need to examine its schematics and check if it has circuitry to:

Prevent current flow from the mainboard 5V to USB, this is usually the case.

Prevent USB 5V from powering the main board, this is usually not included. If you have other 5V circuits on the mainboard that could draw more current than what USB can provide, then you will need to add a diode. Otherwise, it's not necessary.


Here's an example from my PV system:

The board has redundant AC/12VDC and 48VDC/12VDC power supplies, which power fans and relays. Then a 5V buck DC/DC powers the Orange Pi and the Pi Pico. The former manages the PV system, the latter acts as serial-controlled IO expander to send PWM to the fans, monitor tachometer, etc. Both controller modules are mounted on the board and powered through their pin headers. The Pi then powers various USB peripherals.

Thanks! Indeed, it can be mounted in whatever orientation is most convenient... For this Pi I had to mount it at 90° angle because the header is mounted on the same side as the USB connectors, but it's shorter, so if it was mounted as mezzanine, the USB ports would collide with the board! lol
